# Is QC with Superpositioned Quantum Gates any different than normal Quantum Computation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, superposition

This might be more appropriate for theoretical CS stackexchange, but it feels sufficiently low level to be relevant here.

Consider the following thought experiment:

I have a Quantum FPGA, it is a Quantum Computer, whose gates themselves can be controlled programmatically.

For example: Suppose I can have a gate object G which can be in a superposition of being a 1 Qubit Pauli X or a 1 Qubit Hadamard gate. The gate object could then be superpositioned into:

$$a_0  \left| P_x \right>  + a_1  \left|  H \right>$$

So when I apply this gate to a single Qubit $Q = Q_0 \left| 0 \right>+ Q_1 \left| 1 \right>$

The resulting state is

$$ a_0 \left| P_x Q \right> + a_1 \left|H Q \right>$$

$$ a_0  \left|  \left( Q_1  \left| 0 \right> + Q_0 \left| y \right> \right)  \right> +a_1 \left| \left( \frac{Q_0 + Q_1}{\sqrt{2}} \left| 0 \right> + \frac{Q_0 - Q_1}{\sqrt{2}}\left| y \right> \right) \right>  $$

As far sampling the Qubit goes, this state looks identical to perhaps some other composition of concrete gates, but at a high level, it may be possible to determine for example the nature of $G$, in which case, the Qubit collapses to a smaller superposition.

So my question:

Is Quantum Computation with Concrete Gates Equivalent in its computational power to Quantum Computation with Superpositioned Gates?

Obviously they must be equivalent up to Polynomial time differences, simply because the first is capable of simulating any quantum system including the latter in polynomial time. But do we know for fact that the latter class, isn't say polynomially faster?

Something to note here (and switching to matrix notation).

The system is initialized with qubits $A,Q$ of the form:

$$Q =  \begin{bmatrix} Q_0 \\ Q_1 \end{bmatrix} , A =  \begin{bmatrix} A_0 \\ A_1 \end{bmatrix} $$

We have a gate G, that can act as either unitary operator $$ C =  \begin{bmatrix} C_{00} & C_{01} \\ C_{10} & C_{11} \end{bmatrix}, D =  \begin{bmatrix} D_{00} & D_{01} \\ D_{10} & D_{11} \end{bmatrix}   $$

Depending on $A$, and acts on $Q$. So the resulting output is

$$ \begin{bmatrix} A_0 (C_{00} Q_0 + C_{01} Q_1)+ A_1(D_{00}Q_0 + D_{01} Q_1) \\ A_0 ( C_{10} Q_0 + C_{11} Q_1) + A_1 (D_{01} Q_0 + D_{11} Q_1 ) \end{bmatrix} $$

This is a distinctly non-linear process. that cannot be represented using a unitary transform since the output Qubits have probabilities of the form $A_i Q_j$

So while this may be simulated by a Quantum Machine it definitely is doing something a bit different.

Comment: There is nothing special about quantum gates. They are merely random human selections from the set of all possible Hamiltonians. That's no different from classical gates which are also just human selections from the set of all possible Boolean functions. In classical logic a single type of two input gate plus the constants are enough to form an arbitrary function. I don't know how many different quantum gates it takes to achieve the same. My guess is that it's not many.

Comment: It's not clear how to produce the same state I gave using traditional Quantum gates

Comment: Since Gates only yield super positions, not super positions of super positions. Unless those are secretly the same and I'm being silly

Comment: What's the concatenation of two linear operators? A linear operator. One can't go any more linear than linear.

Comment: At CuriousOne, I realize there's a problem here. The operator is not linear. If you allow the gates to be in superpositions of states then given an input vector that both controls the Gate type and has the Gate act on it, we end up with a non linear operator. So it seems... This thought experiment leads to a model that isn't equivalent to Quantum Computation, and may not be physically realizable (or if it could, would lead to much more powerful abilities). See my addendum

Comment: Everything in quantum mechanics is linear.

Comment: So then what I have proposed must be impossible.

Comment: For if the gate is set to superposition by the Qubit it is acting on, then it most certainly won't be a linear transformation

Comment: What you are building here sounds like a simulation of an effective field theory, which can be non-linear, but that's the standard effect of linear QM, already, once you are dealing with more than one degree of freedom, so there is nothing new to be had here.

Comment: Fun question! I think that this is not impossible or non-linear, you have just made a mistake in how to write it down. Your basis states should be the tensor product of Q and A, so the initial state is $(Q_0 A_0, Q_0 A_1, Q_1, A_0, Q_1 A_1)$. This can be mapped to the final state you want by a suitable 4x4 matrix.

Comment: Writing things in this way, it is clear that your superposition of gates can just be reinterpreted as a two-qubit system, with a particular set of interaction gates. So I think the only difference between this and regular circuit QC would be the overhead needed to simulate this set of two qubit gates with the usual CNOT + single qubit operations.

Comment: Ah yes! I understand now @Rococo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a superposed gate is equivalent to a choice of gates controlled by some pre-initialized ancilla qubits, then you can get the exact same effect with a normal gate. Just have the appropriately initialized ancilla be passed in, instead of hidden inside.

I don't think hiding the ancilla inside will give any polynomial benefit in gate count or other metrics. Unless you play games with counting the cost of passing in the ancilla for normal gates, but not counting the cost for superposed gates.

---

Also, be aware that a superposition of gates will act like a probability distribution of gates. At least, it will if the ancilla backing the superposition are not used for anything else.

Clearly you could measure the hidden backing ancilla at the end of the circuit without affecting the already-measured result. But [measurement commutes with controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Measurement_Principle), and the only things on the gates' ancilla qubits are controls. So you can just slide those measurements all the way to the start of the circuit without affecting the expected outcome.

If the backing qubits were already measured at the start, you have a probability distribution of gates instead of a superposition of gates. Which somehow seems a lot less promising, but must be equivalent.